# Where's my I Voted hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2021

I upvoted an answer on SO Meta today, and according to the description of the I Voted hat, you should get it if you upvote *any* question or answer (emphasis mine). There's no mention that meta sites are exempt from this. In fact, the short description says upvote *anywhere* (emphasis mine again). However, I have yet to see that hat.

Comment: Well, I just upvoted this and did not get a hat, maybe the description needs updating...

Comment: Voting should be done on the main site. I voted yesterday and got the hat today

Comment: I received this hat on Meta Stack Exchange as well, so believe meta sites are counted, too

Comment: Also I noticed a couple of hours passed after actual voting and receiving a hat

Comment: Meta.SE is not a meta site, it's a main site. Meta sites don't have rep changes, can't have bounties on questions etc.

Comment: @RafaelTavares OK, didn't know that. Then probably hat description should be updated

Answer (score 4):

Meta sites are not counted for the purposes of the "I Voted" hat. Your vote needs to be cast on the main site—in this case, Stack Overflow.

What can be somewhat confusing is that [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com) *does* count, but that's because it's actually a main site, in the sense that it doesn't have a child Meta site associated with it. The hats you earn for actions taken on Meta Stack Exchange are actually awarded and displayed on Meta Stack Exchange.

It's also worth noting a couple of other things here, with regards to this hat:

- The vote must be on a *post* (i.e., question or answer), not a comment. (This is [now clarified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/373057) in the description.)
- [Yaakov changed the trigger for the hat after the initial deployment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/374089) so that *either* an upvote *or* a downvote on a post is sufficient to earn the hat. (Previously, an upvote was required, which was poorly thought out.)

Comment: In future winter bashes, could the descriptions of those hats that don't count on meta sites be made clear enough that we don't have to keep asking about it? (Maybe add "Cannot be earned on a meta site other than Meta Stack Exchange," or something to that effect to the description?)